# Openstack API behind nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, openstack

I am trying to hide openstack api behind nginx proxy.

```
location /image/api {
  proxy_pass http://192.168.200.1:9292/;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

When I use glance image-list

```
[08/Apr/2014:18:15:07 +0200] 185.39.228.x - - -  to: 192.168.200.1:5000: POST /identity/main/tokens HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time 0.077 msec 1396973707.015 request_time 0.077
185.39.228.x - - [08/Apr/2014:18:15:07 +0200] "POST /identity/main/tokens HTTP/1.1" 200 4128 "-" "python-keystoneclient"
[08/Apr/2014:18:15:07 +0200] 185.39.228.x - - -  to: 192.168.200.1:9292: GET /image/api/v1/images/detail?sort_key=name&sort_dir=asc&limit=20 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time 0.202 msec 1396973707.280 request_time 0.202
185.39.228.x - - [08/Apr/2014:18:15:07 +0200] "GET /image/api/v1/images/detail?sort_key=name&sort_dir=asc&limit=20 HTTP/1.1" 200 3381 "-" "python-glanceclient"
```

But when I use horizon I get error

```
[08/Apr/2014:18:15:29 +0200] 217.20.186.x - - -  to: -: GET /v1/images/detail?limit=21 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time - msec 1396973729.046 request_time 0.000
217.20.186.x - - [08/Apr/2014:18:15:29 +0200] "GET /v1/images/detail?limit=21 HTTP/1.1" 404 177 "-" "python-glanceclient"
```

I see that the link after horizon is a little bit cut, but why?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that horizon sends larger headers with the request than the python client, which exceed the default limit of nginx. For me, setting

```
large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
```

solved the issue.